# Invoking an instantiated method from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

In the MainWindow, I have an instance of a person called jack, and by invoking the method IncreaseElevation I increment Jacks elevation.

In NewWindow I have an instance of a person called jill, and by invoking the method IncreaseElevation I can increment jills elevation.

From NewWindow how do I invoke jack?IncreaseElevation so that the value of jacks Elevation is increased in the MainWindow

I am sure I am missing something obvious.

```
public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _elevation;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Elevation
    {
        get { return _elevation; }
        set
        {
            _elevation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Elevation");
        }
    }

    public void IncreaseElevation()
    {
        Elevation++;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
   Person jack = new Person() { Name = "Jack", Elevation = 0 };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = jack;
    }

    private void OpenNewWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow();

        newWindow.Show();
    }

    private void IncreaseJacksElevation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        jack.IncreaseElevation();
    }
}
```

NewWindow

```
public partial class NewWindow: Window
{
    Person jill = new Person { Name ="Jill", Elevation = 0 };

    public NewWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = jill;
    }

    private void IncreaseJillsElevation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        jill.IncreaseElevation();
    }

    private void IncreaseJacksElevation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to do it, but ultimately you just need a reference to the same `Person` object.  One way would be to provide that reference in the constructor of `NewWindow`:

```
Person jack = null;

public NewWindow(Person _jack)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = jill;
    jack = _jack;
}
```

And when you create `NewWindow`:

```
NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow(jack);
newWindow.Show();
```

Then anywhere you want in `NewWindow` you'll have a usable class-level reference to the same `Person` object:

```
private void IncreaseJacksElevation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    jack.IncreaseElevation();
}
```